# CloudWatch event rule for EC2 health checks

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am looking for an CloudWatch event rule/event pattern to get notified when any of available server's health check is 1/2 passed. When I explored, got the option of CloudWatch alarm but if I have 10 instances, then I need to configure 10 alarms. My aim is to build one single cloudwatch rule using EC2 event or CloudTrail events that will detect ec2 health checks for all servers in region.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to check for the status check metrics. Any value greater than 0 on StatusCheckFailed would mean there's at least one instance with a failed check on either one of the checks. Or you can look for the specific check you want to monitor.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/viewing_metrics_with_cloudwatch.html#status-check-metrics

Comment: status check doesn't include ec2 instance health checks